# NextAuthJS CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR in AWS Amplify

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, next-auth

I have deployed a Next.js app on AWS Amplify and set the NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable to https://app.ikns.info.

However, I'm encountering an error [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] with the following details: 139-601a8d7b508ad4e1.js:1.

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you!"[image]